# Google Closure Compiler moved ?? It's giving a 302 error

Tags: node.js, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm using nodejs 0.4.7 to make the request, this is my code:

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify({  
    'compilation_level' : 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',  
    'output_format': 'json',
      'warning_level' : 'QUIET',
      'js_code' : code
});

var post_options = {  
    host: 'closure-compiler.appspot.com',  
    port: '80',  
    path: 'compile',  
    method: 'POST',  
    headers: {  
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  
        'Content-Length': post_data.length  
    }  
}; 

var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {  
    res.setEncoding('utf8');  
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {  
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);  
    });  
});

post_req.write(post_data);  
post_req.end();
```

And the response I get is

```
Response: <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Why is this happening ? What am I doing wrong ? In the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api.html) it says I'm suposed to make the POST request to http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to send json data:

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify({  
    'compilation_level' : 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',  
    'output_format': 'json',
      'warning_level' : 'QUIET',
      'js_code' : code
});
```

Google Closure Compiler API wants standard form data, so you want to use `querystring` instead. Also you need to indicate the output format you want (compiled code I assume), as specified [by their documentation](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref.html):

```
var post_data = querystring.stringify({  
    'compilation_level' : 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',  
    'output_format': 'json',
    'output_info': 'compiled_code',
      'warning_level' : 'QUIET',
      'js_code' : code
});
```

Path is better declared like so:

```
path: '/compile',
```

Here is the full proof of concept code:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var code ="// ADD YOUR CODE HERE\n" +
"function hello(name) {\n" +
" alert('Hello, ' + name);\n" +
"}\n" +
"hello('New user');\n";

var post_data = querystring.stringify({  
    'compilation_level' : 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',  
    'output_format': 'json',
    'output_info': 'compiled_code',
      'warning_level' : 'QUIET',
      'js_code' : code
});

var post_options = {  
    host: 'closure-compiler.appspot.com',  
    port: '80',  
    path: '/compile',  
    method: 'POST',  
    headers: {  
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  
        'Content-Length': post_data.length  
    }  
}; 

var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {  
    res.setEncoding('utf8');  
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {  
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);  
    });  
});

post_req.write(post_data);  
post_req.end();
```

Running it with `node.js` produces the following:

```
$ node test.js 
Response: {"compiledCode":"alert(\"Hello, New user\");"}
```